# How to disable user interaction on a canvas in UWP app?

Tags: c#, canvas, uwp

I have Implemented a customer signature area in this way. User can draw his signature on this canvas.

```
contacts = new Dictionary<uint, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.Pointer>((int)touchCapabilities.Contacts);
// Declare the pointer event handlers.
Target.PointerPressed += new PointerEventHandler(Target_PointerPressed);
//Target.PointerEntered += new PointerEventHandler(Target_PointerEntered);
Target.PointerReleased += new PointerEventHandler(Target_PointerReleased);
Target.PointerExited += new PointerEventHandler(Target_PointerExited);
//Target.PointerCanceled += new PointerEventHandler(Target_PointerCanceled);
Target.PointerCaptureLost += new PointerEventHandler(Target_PointerCaptureLost);
Target.PointerMoved += new PointerEventHandler(Target_PointerMoved);
Target.PointerWheelChanged += new PointerEventHandler(Target_PointerWheelChanged);

renderer = new XamlInkRenderer(CaptureArea);
```

Now what I want to do is disable the drawings on this canvas (CaptureArea). After disabling it there should not any event generate for user interactions on this canvas. Also I want to re-enable the user interaction if some conditions are satisfied. How can I achieve this? I cannot see any disable function related to canvas object or `XamlInkRenderer` object. Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried  IsHitTestVisible property? Set it false to disable and true to enable. It is available with Canvas as well.

Comment: Thanks! Seems its working

Comment: I have put the same as answer below. Please mark it as an answer and upvote so other user also can take reference when needed. Cheers ! :)

Comment: Done! But I cannot up vote since I'm less than 15 reputations :)

Comment: No problem. If you remember in future , upvote it. I think Your reputation is enough to do that. :)

Comment: @GaurangDave Done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  `IsHitTestVisible` property for `UIElement`. Set it false to disable and true to enable based on conditions you have. It is available with `Canvas` as well.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets or sets a value that declares whether this element can possibly
>   be returned as a hit test result from some portion of its rendered
>   content. This is a dependency property.